# Getting JSON response from Artifactory REST API

Tags: json, curl, artifactory

I always get html repsonce from artifactory api calls from curl. But I need  the response to be in JSON format. For example:  curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET  http://server:port/simple/folders/

What I'm missing in this curl command. Or do I have to change any setting in Artifactory to return response in JSON

Comment: Try `-H "Accept: application/json"`. The `Content-Type` header refers to what you send, not to what you expect as a response. If that does not change anything: Many services accept a URL parameter that switches between response formats. Consult the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you mentioned -  http://server:port/simple/folders/ - is not part of the Artifactory rest API.
The entry point to the REST API is `http://server:port/artifactory/api` (depending on your setup you may not need the 'artifactory' part of the path).
For further information, the latest version of the Artifactory REST API is documented [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API)

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. I'm refering to https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF3X/Artifactory+REST+API coz we use 3.X version. Could NOT find the API URL. I tried http://server:port/artifactory/api/simple/folders/ as well as http://server:port/api/simple/folders/ , both of them are not working.

Comment: 'simple' was not a part of the REST API. It was used for simple browsing and returned an HTML response. If you need to get a list of artifacts/folder you can use the [file list](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileList) API